# Word for a copy of a copy when the copier has never seen the original

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Consider an American who opens a Chinese restaurant but has only eaten at Americanized Chinese restaurants. They are copying something which is already a distorted copy of the original. They could copy it perfectly but it would still be different from real Chinese food.

Is there a word for such a copy? I think Simulacrum is sometimes used this way but isn't actually defined as such.

Comment: I doubt that there is a single word (or short phrase) that means what you want. Just say what it is -- a good copy of American-style Chinese food. You could use *ersatz* (inauthentic).

Comment: Hi Mick, thanks for your comment. I'm aware that it's possible to express this idea directly with a specific phrase. I asked this question because I'm hoping to find a word or short phrase that captures the idea in a general way.

Comment: The situation is sometimes called *Chinese whispers*, but the copy itself is still a *copy*.

Comment: I think @Mick's suggestion of *ersatz* is perfect.  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ersatz

Comment: "Poor imitation" is probably the most idiomatic term, though it doesn't convey the specific meaning of "copy-of-a-copy".

Answer (score 2):

*It was a **second-generation** Chinese restaurant (or chef).*

> 1. A class characterized by the number of reproduction cycles between a copy and the original.
> 2. Something that reflects a significant development from a previous version.
>
> CONTEXT.
>
> Generation does not consider the number of reproductions made from the same source. Rather, it describes the number of times a new source is made from a copy. A print made directly from a negative is described as a first-generation copy. A reproduction from that print is a second-generation copy, and so forth. – Generation is often used to describe major evolutions in technology.
>   - https://definedterm.com/generation_also_copy_status

Answer (score 0):

You could call it the **discount version**.

This new restaurant is the American discount version of a Chinese restaurant.

Comment: That’s assuming that the copy _is_ actually inferior to the original. It may not be; it may just be different.

Comment: A discount version does the same job as the original. but it's not a clone.

Comment: No, a discount version does the same job as the original, _but not as well_ as the original.

Answer (score -1):

The forward looking, bandit marketing, I know I stole it and I know it's not authentic phrase of the the day is "**made it my own**". We took the regular Chinese buffet, and we **made it our own**.

Comment: *Made it our own* describes an adaptation following a study of the original, but I think the OP is looking for a word for which the copier hasn’t experienced the original.